# Another view on mass energy equivalence? $ E = m_0 c^2 [1 - \sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2}]$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, mass-energy, dirac-equation

(this is old thread, but i have edited this question to be more brief)

In the paper, http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0206061.pdf "Fundamental Disagreement of Wave Mechanics with Relativity", and few other papers following that, the author suggests that **the mass to energy conversion** would not be $ E = m_0 c^2 $ ,but it would depend on the velocity: $E(mass- to- Energy)  = m_0 c^2 ( 1 - \sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2} ) $

(The author summarizes there incorrectly that the mass- energy equivalence would be $E = mv^2$ instead of $ E = mc^2 $ - **i think this is wrong statement and is not really what he is saying**, because - first of all there is no concept of relativistic mass $m = m_0 \gamma $, mass is intrinsic property of a particle, he should use instead relativistic momentum $p = m_0 \gamma v $ and the situation is also actually a bit more complicated than this. I write here briefly what he is actually suggesting.)

**The relativistic total energy** of the particle would not be: 
 $$ E_{tot} = m_0\gamma c^2 = \frac{m_0c^2}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$$, but instead it would be: $$ E_{tot} = m_0\gamma v^2 = \frac{m_0v^2}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$$

This suggested total energy can be rewritten also in the following form: $$ E_{tot} = m_0\gamma v^2 = m_0c^2[\gamma - 1/\gamma]= m_0c^2[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}-\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}] $$

**The available energy for mass to energy conversion** would not be:  $$m_0c^2$$, but instead it would be: $$m_0c^2 [1-\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}]$$

**The relativistic kinetic energy** would be still the same: $$E_{kin}= m_0c^2[\gamma -1] = \frac{m_0c^2}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}} - m_0c^2$$

Also **the relativistic momentum** would also be still the same: $$ p(v) = m_0 \gamma v = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2}}$$

But **The relativistic energy - momentum equation** would not be:
$$ E_{tot} = \sqrt{p^2c^2 - m_{0}^{2}c^4 } $$
,but instead:

$$ E_{tot} = pv $$

Note that all the total energy of the particle, energy available to mass to energy conversions and the relativistic kinetic energy of the particle would be now all 0 when the particle is in the relative rest: 
$$ E_{tot} \rightarrow 0 ,  when: v \rightarrow 0$$

And when the velocity approaches the light velocity the same quantities would approach the commonly accepted values:

$$ E_{tot} \rightarrow m_0\gamma c^2 ,  when:  v \rightarrow c $$
$$ E_{mass_to_energy} \rightarrow m_0c^2,  when:  v \rightarrow c $$

Note also that in this proposition, there is no concept of 'rest energy'.

As i have read these papers, the author does not falsify nor prove his claim, but he studies different kind of implications from that. There is no analysis that can directly disprove or prove his claim.

**This suggestion is interesting** because the particle theories such as quantum mechanics accept the common mass to energy equivalence as a postulate, that is inserted to the theory from outside the theory.

this is old thread, and thank you for all answers you have answered before.

The question is, **how to prove or disprove this claim?**

Comment: The question seems to be incorrect. The relations does not compare with the standard ones. The justification is not clear. There is a strange mixture between special relativity and early quantum mechanics. Needs clarification.

Comment: the fact that de broglie frequency relation includes term muv^2 is just an interesting coincidence i happen to notice.

Comment: Is the paper <[arXiv:physics/0402038v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0402038v1)>, the actual paper you are referring to? More specifically, are you referring to section 1 (pp. 5–9) of the paper? If yes, then do you use the same notation as the paper?

Comment: The author has actually made 9 articles on the subject, where he conciders various topics how Quantum mechanical theory and Dirac theory changes when mass energy equivalence E=mv2 is applied instead of E=mc². I understand that the total energy of a particle is actually inserted into QM as assumption, and when this assumption is changed, the theories it is applied to gives different results on all properties that are connected to the starting point assumption that total energy of particle is given by special relativity. I think this article is best : http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0402038

Comment: However the justification of the new formula in not clear to me. I expressed above his new proposal in the form of total energy equation, to put all together in simple form.

Comment: (but if this new assumption is not justified, then of course all speculation he makes in that is based on it is not correct.)

Comment: I notice that all nine articles are single author; that all were posted between 2002 and 2009; that the three that have seen publication were placed in *Physics Essays* in 2002 and 2003; and that most of the citations to these articles are self-citations. The idea doesn't seem to have much support.

Answer (score 1):

The proper generalization to quantum mechanics appears to be generalizing the least action principle to one where every path with an action $S$ receives an amplitude $e^{iS/\hbar}$ of occurrence: in the classical limit such rotating phases will cancel out except at minima of the action and thus you will recover least-action mechanics, while deviations from those paths will become probable in a quantum way.

The action for a free particle should be a Lorentz scalar, so that everyone agrees on the equations of motion. The absolute simplest such action integral is $\alpha \int d\tau,$ where $\alpha$ must be a Lorentz scalar, too, dependent perhaps on the kind of the particle but, for simplicity, independent of the path.  Given that action integral, the Lagrangian for the free particle is $L = \alpha / \gamma,$ since the proper time is related to your local coordinate's time by $d\tau = dt / \gamma.$ So the simplest candidate "free particle" Lagrangian turns out to be$$L = \alpha \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}.$$

To recover classical mechanics, we can simply expand this Lagrangian in terms of $v^2$ and we find that the leading terms are $\alpha~(1 - \frac12~v^2/c^2).$ To recapture the classical Lagrangian's form we absolutely have to require that $\alpha = -m_0 c^2$ so that this looks like $\text{arbitrary constant} + \frac12 m v^2.$ Here $m_0$ must be the rest mass precisely because we said $\alpha$ must be a Lorentz scalar, and it must be the Lorentz scalar which looks like mass at 0 velocity.

Given that simple argument, your **total energy** is fixed up to an additive constant, which can *not* be dependent on $\vec v.$ Why? Because now that we have the Lagrangian we know the canonical momentum in any reference frame:$$\vec p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec v}= -m_0c^2 ~\cdot~ \frac12 \left(1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2}~\cdot~\left(-2\frac{\vec v}{c^2}\right),\text{ or,}\\\vec p =\gamma~m_0~\vec v.$$The canonical momentum is useful precisely because the total energy (Hamiltonian) is defined as the Legendre transform of the Lagrangian; it is always $\vec p\cdot\vec v - L.$ Applying this in this case:$$H = \vec p \cdot \vec v - L = \gamma~m_0~v^2 + m_0~c^2/\gamma,\text{ or,}\\
H = \gamma~m_0~\left(v^2 + c^2 \left[1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}\right]\right) = \gamma~m_0~c^2.$$

Therefore the paper you are thinking about must be implicitly pursuing one of four aims:

1. Nonsense for its own sake,
2. In the proper relativistic generalization, individual reference frames have Hamiltonians which are not the total energy,
3. In the proper relativistic generalization, we can not define an action principle, or,
4. There is a different relativistically-covariant action principle that is not just the proper time (up to a coefficient of proportionality).

Obviously we cannot help you with (1). The aims of (2) and (3) are interesting, however, *modern theoretical physics has not needed to abandon these yet*, and in fact action principles of precisely this sort underlie modern quantum field theory.

I actually claim agnosticism as to (4). It is very unlikely that you can get a quantum mechanical action-treatment to play nice with the nonlinear-seeming action $\left(\int d\tau\right)^2,$ for example, but it *would* be covariant. Similarly, there should be some freedom to drop the assumption that everyone agrees on the numeric values of the action, as long as we agree on the 4-trajectories of the particles. So it seems like there's a few ways you could go in those directions.

Comment: this link http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0402038v1.pdf "dialogue on the principle of ..." in pages 5-9 chapter 2.1 "the invariants of the minkowsky spacetime..." the author of the article deals with similar issue and derives different 4-momentum. i cannot follow it from first sight step by step however.

Comment: he express length invariant as I = [x,y,z,ict]. looks like that he argues that 4-velocity should be u = [0,0,0,0] and that there is no reason to treat the time component as constant (first column in page 8) -which i think is his main argument

Comment: the 4-momentum he gets is then p = um[vx,vy,vz,i(v^2/c)] where u is lorentz gamma factor and m is mass of the particle

Comment: @CR Drost: Could you please also explain the original question by `Sami M`? The question itself and the justification is not so clear in the first place.

Comment: @SamiM Glancing over the paper, he appears to have a problem with the interpretation of $dr^\bullet/d\tau$ as having a time component having anything to do with the velocity, and instead states that everyone should use a modified version; let $w = ct$ and $\hat w^\bullet = (1,\vec 0)$ then he is saying that everyone should insist on the time component of the "correct" 4-velocity as being 0 and therefore use $v^\bullet = dr^\bullet/d\tau - \gamma |v| \hat w^\bullet$ to describe the particle; the fact that $\hat w^\bullet$ is not Lorentz-covariant is something to be shrugged and accepted.

Comment: @SamiM I also see 3 major difficulties: (1) His theory of particle decay is not relativistic: he requires particles to be "moving" but of course every particle has a rest frame; the implication would be that particles cannot decay without being accelerated, which is probably already violated by experiment. (2) His explanation of the electron-positron spectrum demands that electrons and positrons go superluminal half the time when they approach each other? (3) He can't get a non-relativistic limit without a vacuum-energy handwave that'd probably throw off every calculation he's ever made.

Comment: @Khwārazmi The question refers to speculations by an electrical engineer who reasons: "quantum mechanics says $E=hf$ and $p=h/\lambda$ and we know $f\lambda=v$ and $p=mv,$ so QM only works if $E=pv=mv^2.$" He thinks that this is "right" but it's not clearly "relativistic" so he wants to connect it to the relativistic $E=\gamma mc^2$ by insisting that the quantum-relativistic case is given by $E=\gamma mv^2,$ which he "derives" by insisting that the $c$ in the four-vector $(ct, \vec r)$ be made to vary with proper time in just such a way that the four-velocity is $(0,\vec 0)$ in the rest frame.

Comment: @Khwārazmi He derives that the resulting non-covariant four-velocity is then $(\gamma v^2/c, \gamma \vec v)$ in other reference frames and interprets it as $m_0^{-1}~(E/c,\vec p)$ in the usual way. The question as I read it is therefore: Is this derivation useful, and is there a way to connect either $\gamma m_0 c^2$ or $\gamma m_0 v^2$ to the Hamiltonian of a particle so that we can actually have a solid basis to think about "total energy", rather than this airy-fairy stuff about what someone thinks that quantum mechanics is saying?

Comment: i found that in article http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0411067 in page 3 he derives lagrangian - in equations 7-8 he argues that the lagrangian should be L=mc²[1-1/u] instead of L=mc²[1/u] where u is lorentz gamma factor u=1/sqrt[1-(v/c)²], by saying that ordinary derivation forgets the integration constant when calculating the integral

Comment: CR Drost , sorry i just noticed that you have also made 3 other comments

Comment: also in same article page 4 -5 he calculates the action A = integral (L), 5 after having equation (12): action A= integral (kinetic energy)dt , he argues that the action should not be assumed to be lorentz-invariant.

Comment: and in article http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0206061 page 6 he by starting integral equation (17) for kinetic energy, he uses intergration by parts (22) to calculate the energy integral, when he gets Ekin = muv² - mc² [1-1/u] = mc² [u-1/u] - mc² [1-1/u]. the Ekin is exactly same, but now the two terms in the right side of the equation are different- both of them have additional term -1/u   (u is lorentz gamma factor u=1/sqrt[1-(v/c)²]

Comment: note that there is identity: muv² = mc² [u-1/u]

Comment: @SamiM His paper #0411067 speaks to condition (4) in my answer: it is possible that $mv^2$ can be derived from a Lagrangian which is not Lorentz-covariant, but whose solutions are. However, he screws up equations (13,14): the $H=\gamma m_0v^2$ is not the canonical Hamiltonian $pv-L$ for that Lagrangian; $L$ is great but $H=\gamma m_0v^2=p^2/(\gamma m_0)=p^2/\sqrt{m_0^2+p^2/c^2}$  just seems functionally different from the tried-and-tested Hamiltonian $H=\sqrt{p^2 c^2 + m_0^2 c^4}$ that comes from $L=m_0 c^2(1 - 1/\gamma).$

Comment: looks like he assumes there before eq (14) that hamiltonian corresponds to total energy. His new total energy: H = Etot = muv² = mc^2[u-1/u] . This pv = muv² = Etot and L = Ex = mc²[1-1/u] , which makes H to be H = pv instead of H = pv - L.

Comment: @SamiM Yes, that's precisely the problem. If you're going to call something "total energy" you'd best demonstrate that it's a conserved scalar; if you're going to call something a "Hamiltonian" I'd like to see Hamilton's equations of motion; Hamilton's equations straightforwardly show the Hamiltonian to be conserved which is why we identify it with energy. Since his Hamiltonian doesn't lead to the equations of motion seen in his Lagrangian, it is not the Hamiltonian of the system; if it is conserved it is only obviously due to the simplicity of the system.

Comment: (this is just a thought, but can this scalar m0c^2 be interpreted not as energy, but something else. for example as a frequency f0 = mc^2/h that is connected to mass )

Comment: @SamiM: Well there is the mundane observation that you don't see e.g. pair production events until your photons have that frequency. However one model of cosmology, the conformal cyclic cosmology, qualitatively works that way too: Rest mass may be necessary to form clocks, and may form only due to particle interaction; if so then some day long after the black holes evaporate, our universe will essentially Big Rip so that each particle is in its own universe... far from being a bad thing, the particles are all massless and travel to infinity in zero proper time since they don't experience time.

Comment: if i understand right, equations of motion that does not involve mass to energy conversions,would be exactly same - the kinetic energy of the particle is still mc^2[u-1/u] . But this new interpretation gives new quantitave predictions to every event that includes mass to energy conversions. now the available energy from mass is m0c^2[1-1/u] instead of m0c^2. one prediction is that in every annihilation, the particles should accelerate to near light velocity in order to convert their whole mass to a pair of photons. But the real question is, what is the mechanism behind mass energy conversions?

Comment: if i understand correctly, there still is a scalar m0c^2, but i think that with this interpretation it has nothing to do with the rest energy of a particle. Other difference is, That new energy component m0c^2 [1-1/u] may be an extrintric property of a particle, not an intrinsic property.

Comment: (there is mistake in my above comment the formula of kinetic energy, it should be Ekin = mc^2 [u-1])

Comment: I mean, it's hard to say whether equations of motion which do not involve mass-to-energy conversions would be the exact same; we know for example that his Hamiltonian does not reproduce good results even in the classical case without an ass-pull to explain the disappearance of the $\frac12$ factor. At some point it just becomes easier to do these things the normal way -- and "it's easier" is how science actually does theory-choice; we don't have any special insights about truth but rather we just try to make the most meaningful predictions with the least amount of effort.

Comment: i think the new mass-energy equivalence should be stated as "available energy in mass to energy conversions is: E = m0c^2[1-1/u]", which is more clear than statement "total energy of particle equals to E=m0uv^2 = m0c^2[u-1/u]."  in classical velocities, when v << c ,this available energy is approximately to E = (1/2)m0v^2 so it is equal to kinetic energy in low velocities. And now total energy becomes E=m0v^2 ,when v << c .

Comment: he suggests that this $$ E= m_0c^2(1-1/u) $$ is vacuum energy in http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0402038v1.pdf page 2 Q2 answer without further thought

Answer (score 0):

To be blunt, any consideration that starts assuming that $E = mc^2$ has a special place in relativity (heh!) is likely to be wrong.

The right starting place is always from<sup>1</sup> 
$$ (mc^2)^2 = E^2 - (pc)^2 \,, $$
and in that framework there is simply no way to avoid the usual assignment of the rest energy and kinetic energy. And at that point the rest simply collapses.

Remember kids, relativistic invariants are where it is at. All the cool people use them

---

<sup>1</sup> Because it handles both massive and massless particles and is good at all velocities, that's why.